# Git - cómo crear otra configuración aparte de la que tengo?

Tags: git

Tengo mi configuración global en la que tengo puesto:

- Usuario
- Contraseña
- URL de origen.

Pero necesito cambiar esos datos para clonar otro repositorio y manejar otro nombre de usuario y URL ¿Cómo puedo configurar eso?

Comment: Deberías indicar como creaste la configuración *global* esa que indicas. Pásate por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos opciones

### Opción 1.

No quiero cambiar mis datos globales, si no que quiero cambiar los del archivo.

En ese caso utiliza el comando:

`git remote set-url origin`

Con el nombre de usuario, contraseña y url correspondiente, aquí te quedo un ejemplo de como se haría en Github:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

### Opción 2

Cambiar el nombre de tu usuario y contraseña en global, para ellos usamos los siguientes comandos:

- Borrar anteriores nombre y contraseña usando `git config --global --unset user.password`
- Poner Nombre: `git config --global user.name "Nombre"`
- Poner Contraseña: `git config --global --add user.password "Contraseña"`